How to add a font from google for Sphinx
I've tried adding a font from google to Sphinx, this font over here. I've tried to follow this post's instructions (in the comments) so far, and did this:

Create a file named styles.css , and placed this code inside, importing my font from google:
@import url('https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Sorts+Mill+Goudy?query=goudy+old+style');


Place this line of code inside conf.py :
def setup(app):
    app.add_stylesheet('styles.css')


Used make html to build the Sphinx files. When I attempted to do this, I got hit with a error, saying:
Running Sphinx v7.4.7
loading translations [en]... done
/Users/jonathanfong/DocStrings/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py:35: NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'LibreSSL 2.8.3'. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/3020
  warnings.warn(

Exception occurred:
  File "/Users/jonathanfong/DocStrings/docs/source/conf.py", line 33, in setup
    app.add_stylesheet('styles.css')
AttributeError: 'Sphinx' object has no attribute 'add_stylesheet'
The full traceback has been saved in /var/folders/qz/dxx7vhbd37535w1c245jwdm80000gp/T/sphinx-err-79u1zqel.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks!
make: *** [html] Error 2

Am I doing something wrong with importing the font? And the original post's instructions were a bit unclear though, so I'm quite confused.


Any and all help would be appreaciated.

Your google fonts URL links to a specimen page. You need a valid CSS URL like https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sorts+Mill+Goudy:ital@0;1&display=swap   returning a CSS with @font-face rules.

The add_stylesheet() method was removed in Sphinx 6.0. Use add_css_file() instead.
See also https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/deprecated.html.

I've tried the following: Create a file names styles.css in _static, and placed the following: @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sorts+Mill+Goudy:ital@0;1&display=swap');, then placed this code in conf.py, def setup(app):     app.add_css_file('styles.css'), but it's still not working. There are no crashes or failing builds, just that the font isnt rendering.

Maybe you forgot to add a rule with font-family: "Sorts Mill Goudy"; in styles.css?

This continues in https://stackoverflow.com/q/78962032/407651

finally found the answer for everyone curious: a line in conf.py was pointing to the wrong folder
