A font I imported from Google Fonts isn't rendering (Sphinx)
I am trying to import a font from google fonts, this one, but it is not rendering. I've been following this post, but it's not really working.
I've asked this question before, and when I encountered more difficulties, I was told to make a new post, as people have already answered my question in the old post.
I am using Sphinx 8.0.2, Myst-Parser 4.0.0, and the Alabaster theme.
I have done the following:

Create a file named styles.css in the _templates directory, and added the following lines of code to styles.css:

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sorts+Mill+Goudy:ital@0;1&display=swap');

.sorts-mill-goudy-regular {
    font-family: "Sorts Mill Goudy", serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
  .sorts-mill-goudy-regular-italic {
    font-family: "Sorts Mill Goudy", serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
  }


Next, I added this line of code to conf.py:

def setup(app):
    app.add_css_file('styles.css')


Ran make html in a terminal to build my Documentation. The build works, and there is no errors, but the font just isn't rendering, and it's still the normal font Alabaster uses.

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thank you.

The CSS should work fine. Could it be the theme's CSS is simply overriding your rules? You could try a more specific rule like *{font-family: "Sorts Mill Goudy"!important} for testing - this should override even subsequent rules.

@herrstrietzel i take it i place this code in styles.css? And I were to place it in there, how so. But thanks for the help so far
